# C++ : base64 to PNG backslash issue

Tags: c++, base64, png, converters

I'm trying to convert a png file to a base64 but when I'm write the output to a file, I have a lot of backslash like this : data:image\/png;base64

My code :

```
string encoded_png;
Mat img; // Load an image here

vector<uchar> buf;
cv::imencode(".png", img, buf);
auto base64_png = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(buf.data());
encoded_png = "data:image/png;base64," + base64_encode(base64_png, buf.size());
```

Comment: Can you show how you are writing the data to a file?

Comment: What is `base64_encode`? What does it return?

Comment: @RetiredNinja    


   boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
pt.put("link", encoded_png);


   std::stringstream ss;
   boost::property_tree::json_parser::write_json(ss, pt);
   ofstream myfile;
   myfile.open(path);
   myfile << ss.str();
   myfile.close();

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude https://github.com/ReneNyffenegger/cpp-base64 this is the function for convert to base64 and it return a std::string

Comment: You should edit the code for saving the data into your question. It is the most important detail and comments can be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping `/` as `\/` is perfectly valid in JSON. Any parser should interpret the escaped character as just a `/`.